# $\exists a\in G-H$ such that $aHa^{-1}=H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group with proper subgroup $H$. Show that there exists an element
$a\in G -H$ such that $a^{-1} Ha = H$

Can you check my proof?

Since $G$ and $H$ are $p$-groups their centers $Z(G)$, $Z(H)$ are nontrivial. The centers satisfy $Z(H) \leq Z(G)$ and $Z(H) = H\cap Z(G)$.

If $Z(H)< Z(G)$ then $\exists a\in Z(G)$ such that $a\in G-H$ and $ \ \ a^{-1}Ha=H$

If $Z(G) = Z(H) \rightarrow H = Z(G)$ every element of $H$ commutes with every element of $G$ so $\exists a\in G-H \ | \ a^{-1}Ha=a^{-1}aH=eH=H$

I feel like i dindnt proof anything. Is there a better alternative, preferably with group actions?

Comment: how come $\;Z(H)\le Z(G)\;$ ? How did you prove that?

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_whose_center_is_contained_in_the_center_of_the_whole_group

Comment: It's definitely not true in general that if $H\leq G$ then $Z(H)\leq Z(G)$.

Comment: wikipedia had it, i'm assuming its true?

Comment: No @abe, wikipedia doesn't have anything of the like. I think you're misunderstanding something in that link you wrote...

Comment: @Abe, have you already studied nilpotent groups? Do you know a finite $\;p$-group is nilpotent?

Comment: Well, first of all, that the link isn't Wikipedia :)

Comment: @abe "The notion of subgroup whose center is contained in the center of the whole group has the following equivalent definitions" : its a definition, they say that subgroup $H$ such that $Z(H)\leq Z(G)$ are some kind of subgroup, but they never say it was a valid equation for all subgroups.

Comment: No @abe, it is not that at all...since in **any** finite group we have that $\;x^{|G|}=e\;\;\forall\,x\in G\;$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's claim is true in any nilpotent group, and for finite groups it is actually equivalent to being nilpotent, but here are the highlights of a proof without using group nilpotency:

Let $\;G\;$ be a finite $\;p$-group, $\;H\lneq G\;$ . Let us define an action of $\;H\;$ on the set $\;X\;$ of left cosets of $\;H\;$ in $\;G\;$ by left shifting:

$$\forall\,h\in H\;,\;\forall\,g\in G\;\;:\;\;\;h\cdot(gH):=(hg)H$$

Since $\;H\;$ is a $\;p$-group, the orbit-staiblizer theorem tells us that every orbit is a divisor of $\;p\;$. But since $\;|\mathcal Orb(H)|=1\;$, there **must be** another orbit with only one element (why?), and this means

$$\exists\,g\notin H\;\;s.t.\;\;\forall\,h\in H\;,\;\;h\cdot(gH)=gh\iff hgH=gH\iff g^{-1}hg\in H$$

and we're done.

You can also use induction and go into the quotient group $\;G/Z(G)\;$ and etc.

Comment: $|Orb(H)| = 1$ because $\forall h\in H \ \ hH = H$. Since the orbits partition the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$,when you sum all the orbits you have to get $[G:H]$. Since there is an orbit with $|Orb|=1$ there has to be another one so that they can add up to some multiple of $p$. Let $gH$ where $g\notin H$ be the other left coset of $H$ with $|Orb(gH)|=1$ Then $Orb(gH) = \{ xH\in S \ | xH = h*(gH) \ for \ some \ h\in H   \}= \{ h*(gH) =gH \forall h\in H \}$ so $hgH=gH \rightarrow g^{-1}hgH= H \rightarrow g^{-1}hg\in H$

Comment: I get it now :D. Can you check my interpretation of your proof? Also, how do you know which group action and set to choose for a problem? Is there a method?

Comment: Looks fine, @abe...and about knowing: experience and practice.